# Copying sets Java

Tags: java, copy, set

Is there a way to copy a `TreeSet`? That is, is it possible to go

```
Set <Item> itemList;
Set <Item> tempList;

tempList = itemList;
```

or do you have to physically iterate through the sets and copy them one by one?

Comment: `tempList.addAll(itemList)`

Answer (score 169, accepted):

Another way to do this is to use the [copy constructor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet%28java.util.Collection%29):

```
Collection<E> oldSet = ...
TreeSet<E> newSet = new TreeSet<E>(oldSet);
```

Or create an empty set and add the elements:

```
Collection<E> oldSet = ...
TreeSet<E> newSet = new TreeSet<E>();
newSet.addAll(oldSet);
```

Unlike `clone` these allow you to use a different set class, a different comparator, or even populate from some other (non-set) collection type.

---

<sup>Note that the result of copying a `Set` is a new `Set` containing references to the objects that are elements if the original `Set`.  The element objects themselves are not copied or cloned.  This conforms with the way that the Java `Collection` APIs are designed to work: they don't copy the element objects.</sup>

Answer (score 10):

Starting from **Java 10**:

```
Set<E> oldSet = Set.of();
Set<E> newSet = Set.copyOf(oldSet);
```

[`Set.copyOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection)) returns an unmodifiable `Set` containing the elements of the given `Collection`.

The given `Collection` must not be `null`, and it must not contain any `null` elements.

Answer (score 7):

With Java 8 you can use `stream` and `collect` to copy the items:

```
Set<Item> newSet = oldSet.stream().collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or you can collect to an `ImmutableSet` (if you know that the set should not change):

```
Set<Item> newSet = oldSet.stream().collect(ImmutableSet.toImmutableSet());
```

Comment: You can ... but the copy constructor (etc) should be more efficient if you are simply copying a collection.

Answer (score 4):

**Java 8+**:

```
Set<String> copy = new HashSet<>(mySet);
```

Answer (score 3):

The copy constructor given by @Stephen C is the way to go when you have a `Set` you created (or when you know where it comes from).
When it comes from a [`Map.entrySet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet%28%29), it will depend on the `Map` implementation you're using:

[findbugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/) says

> The entrySet() method is allowed to return a view of the underlying
>   Map in which a single Entry object is reused and returned during the
>   iteration. As of Java 1.6, both IdentityHashMap and EnumMap did so.
>   When iterating through such a Map, the Entry value is only valid until
>   you advance to the next iteration. If, for example, you try to pass
>   such an entrySet to an addAll method, things will go badly wrong.

As `addAll()` is called by the copy constructor, you might find yourself with a Set of only one Entry: the last one.

Not all `Map` implementations do that though, so if you know your implementation is safe in that regard, the copy constructor definitely is the way to go. Otherwise, you'd have to create new `Entry` objects yourself:

```
Set<K,V> copy = new HashSet<K,V>(map.size());
for (Entry<K,V> e : map.entrySet())
    copy.add(new java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<K,V>(e));
```

Edit: Unlike tests I performed on Java 7 and Java 6u45 (thanks to Stephen C), the findbugs comment does not seem appropriate anymore. It might have been the case on earlier versions of Java 6 (before u45) but I don't have any to test.

Comment: Is this based on observation?  If so, that sounds like a bug in the `addAll` implementation.  FWIW, the `Map` implementations I have looked all iterate the entry set (at some level), and *extract the key and value for each one*.  The fact that the entry set iterator might return the same object each doesn't time doesn't matter. The only case I saw that was different was `EnumMap` where the copy constructor itself was cloning the entries ...  if the source map was an `EnumMap`.

Comment: @StephenC it seems you're right: the tests I've done with `IdentityHashMap` do not lead to that bug. More troubling is that I tested it on Java 6u45 and there was no problem either. I guess this is a bug in findbugs (or the JDK they based their rules on...).

I'll edit my answer.