# Java - convert unmodifiable sets in a map(key, set) to modifaible

Tags: java, collections, set, guava, unmodifiable

I implemented a function which return `Map<key,Set<objects>>` , when I call this function it return the sets with type Unmodifiable.

I need to do some operations to this sets, how to convert them to modifiable sets in best practice? Otherwise I got

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `Map` itself is mutable, you use something like

```
map.replaceAll((key, set) -> new HashSet<>(set));
```

Example:

```
Map<Integer,Set<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(5, Collections.emptySet());
map.put(10, Collections.singleton("foo"));

map.replaceAll((key, set) -> new HashSet<>(set));

map.get(5).add(42);
map.get(10).add("bar");

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
5=[42]
10=[bar, foo]
```

Of course, you can also replace `new HashSet<>(set)` with `new TreeSet<>(set)` or generally every `Set` implementation type following the copy constructor convention. When you can’t use a copy constructor, you have to resort to `addAll`, e.g.

```
map.replaceAll((key, set) -> {
    TreeSet<Object> newSet = new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Object::toString));
    newSet.addAll(set);
    return newSet;
});
```

---

There’s another option. Instead of converting all values of the map, only convert the sets on demand, i.e. when you actually want to modify them and they turn out not to have the intended type:

```
Map<Integer,Set<Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(5, Collections.emptySet());
map.put(10, Collections.singleton("foo"));

map.computeIfPresent(5, (key,set)->set instanceof HashSet? set: new HashSet<>()).add(42);
map.computeIfPresent(10, (key,set)->set instanceof HashSet?set:new HashSet<>()).add("bar");

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could copy the [original set to another one that can be modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537361/copying-sets-java).

Something like this:

```
Set<YourType> newSet = unmodifiableSet
                        .stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.toSet());
// Or maybe...
Set<YourTYpe> otherSet = new HashSet<>();
otherSet.addAll(unmodifiableSet);
```

Then, you could modify the new list without any problem, and re-assign it into the map.

Comment: yes that exactly what i did, but I was searching for something more practical than looping through all the map to transfer set by set. Also I can't understand why it turns to be unmodifiable, do you have any idea?

Comment: To know why it turns unmodifiable, please post the code which is returning the map

Comment: Can you show me how are you returning the Map from your function? Maybe we can figure out why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

## Just use the copy constructor

For a `HashSet`:

```
Set<Type> modifiable = new HashSet<>(unmodifiable);
```

For a `TreeSet`:

```
SortedSet<Type> modifiable = new TreeSet<>(unmodifiable);
```

For a `LinkedHashSet`:

```
Set<Type> modifiable = new LinkedHashSet<>(unmodifiable);
```

If you use a fancy Set implementation without such constructor:

```
Set<Type> modifiable = new MyFancySet<>();
modifiable.addAll(unmodifiable);
```

Comment: I use HashSet and that's whats I did for each set in the map. But instead of going trough key by key in the map and copying the set into a new map is there a better solution?

Comment: @AlaaKhalil You should definitely add your code that show how you create and populate the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that as a one-liner with `Streams`:

*With `map` being your original map (e.g. `Map<Integer, ImmutableSet<Object>> map;`)*

```
Map<Integer, Set<Object>> mutableMap = map.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Sets::newHashSet));
```